# Replicating Pivot Table pagefields in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, pivot-table

I have a report that takes a months worth of sales data and shows a bar chart of it broken down by half hour block so that the recipient can see what the busy times of day are over a long period. I think that they would also like the option to look at a particular date within the dataset. In Excel I would just throw the Date column into the pagefield (report filter) section of the PivotTable/PivotChart and the recipient could use the resulting dropdown box to filter on dates to their hearts content. Is there a way to replicate this kind of functionality in SSRS? I have tried adding Date to the chart data set up as a series group but this just splits the data automatically. I want the default to be all the months data with the option to choose date(s) if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a parameter, there are different ways.
Here's 1 way:

Create two Parameters **StartDate** and **EndDate**. Then choose Datatype as **Date/Time**. It will show a calendar then the user can set it manually by choosing dates.

After creating the parameters. on your dataset. right click then **Properties** > **Filters.**
Click add then on the expression choose the Date field on your dataset then Operator = Between. On the value put [@StartDate] and [@EndDate].

Comment: Will this only work when the report runs though? I want a solution that can work after the report has been run and delivered. The recipients will not have access to SSRS and will only be able to access the delivered Excel file.